# Inheriting a button from BaseViewController class using Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

I have two classes

1. `ViewController` (BaseClass) 2. `DerivedViewController` (Derived class)

I have a textbox in `ViewController` class. Is it possible to use that textbox in `DerivedViewController` class via inheritance?

If yes, how to inherit that textbox ?

I tried following code for inheritance and i inherited successfully by importing `ViewController.h` as follows.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h>

@interface DerivedViewController : ViewController

@end
```

Now my problem is, how to use that `textField` in this `DerivedViewController`. I am trying to achieve Reusability concept of inheritance. As i am using storyboard, it's so confusing how to get that `textField` and place it in this ViewController box in storyboard.

Thanks for the time :)

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstTB;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *secondTB;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *symbolLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *find;


@end

@implementation ViewController

int resultValue=0;



- (IBAction)saveResult:(id)sender {
    if((self.firstTB.text.length == 0) || self.secondTB.text.length == 0){
        [self showError];
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }else{
        int number1 = [[[self firstTB] text] intValue];
        int number2 = [[[self secondTB] text] intValue];
        resultValue=number1+number2;
        NSLog(@"%d",resultValue);
        [self saveData];
        [self removeShadow];
    }

}
- (IBAction)listResults:(id)sender {
  //  [self findData];
}



//Save Data.........

-(void) saveData{
    BOOL success = NO;
    NSString *alertString = @"Data Insertion failed";
    success = [[DBManager getSharedInstance]saveData:
               resultValue];


    if (success == NO) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                              alertString message:nil
                                                      delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    if(success == YES){
        NSLog(@"FY %d",resultValue);
    }
}

  //Find data.......
-(void) findData {

    int n = [[DBManager getSharedInstance]findResult:[[[self find] text] intValue]];
    if (n == 0) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                              @"Data not found" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:
                              @"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
    else{
      /*  regNoTextField.text = findByRegisterNumberTextField.text;
        nameTextField.text =[data objectAtIndex:0];
        departmentTextField.text = [data objectAtIndex:1];
        yearTextField.text =[data objectAtIndex:2];  */
        NSLog(@"Data Found %d",n);

    }
}




// For Shadow..... 

-(void)showError{
    [self addShadow];
}


-(void)addShadow{
    if(self.firstTB.text.length == 0 && self.secondTB.text.length == 0){

        [self glowfirstTB:YES];

        [self glowsecondTB:YES];

    }else if(self.firstTB.text.length == 0){

        [self glowfirstTB:YES];

        [self glowsecondTB:NO];

    }else if(self.secondTB.text.length == 0){

        [self glowsecondTB:YES];

        [self glowfirstTB:NO];
    }


}

-(void)removeShadow{
    [self glowfirstTB:NO];
    [self glowsecondTB:NO];
}

-(void)glowfirstTB:(BOOL) shall_I_Glow{
    if(shall_I_Glow){
        self.firstTB.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        self.firstTB.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
        self.firstTB.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
        self.firstTB.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
        self.firstTB.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
    }else{
        self.firstTB.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0f;
        self.firstTB.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
    }
}


-(void)glowsecondTB:(BOOL) shall_I_Glow{
    if(shall_I_Glow){
        self.secondTB.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        self.secondTB.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
        self.secondTB.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
        self.secondTB.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
        self.secondTB.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;

        // [self.num setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
        // self.passwordTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
    }else{
        self.secondTB.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0f;
        self.secondTB.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
    }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**DerivedViewController.m (Which is named as SearchPage.h here)**

```
#import "SearchPage.h"

@interface SearchPage ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *searchText;

@end

@implementation SearchPage

- (IBAction)findButton:(id)sender {
   self.firstTB.text = @"hello";
   //Error message : Property 'firstTB' not found on object of type "SearchPage"
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: Do you want to just access the textView or you want to show the same textView on ViewControllers screen?

Comment: want to use same TextBox on both screens (Both ViewControllers)

Comment: If you want to show same textView on both Base and Derived ViewController then you have to add textView on both ViewController from Storyboard and create a subclass of UITextView and set the properties you want to set, and set that class as a custom class of both ViewControllers TextViews Custom Class. Just to clear things- If you are thinking like adding TextView on BaseViewControllers and inheriting the same in ChildViewController will not show TextView automatically, you would need to add textView on both ViewControllers on storyboard.

Comment: If i need to add textView on both viewcontrollers , then how it will count as REUSING same textView. ?

Comment: is it possible to reuse ? Like we are calling 'variables and functions' of base class from derived class.

Comment: If you just want to access the content of textView like we does in case of variable then it can be done by just inheriting the base class but if you want to show textView on both screen then you must add textView on both ViewControllers from storyboard, and create a common outlet for both as said by Shan.

Answer (score 1):

yes, u can use the same text box added in the `ViewController` in `DerivedViewController`, for this u add one more `textbox` in the `DerivedViewController's` scene and connect the `IBOutlet` to `ViewController 's`  `textbox` no need to create a new outlet for `textbox` in the  `DerivedViewController` this way u can inherit the `textbook`.

Edit 1:

if u subclass the `ViewController` all the outlet connections are available in `DerivedViewController` subclass. for example,in `DerivedViewController` just drag from `files owner` to your view component it will show the superview's (ViewController's) outlet name

edit 2:
u are declaring the private properties, so make it available for other classes also by declaring in `.h` file,

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h>

@interface DerivedViewController : ViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstTB;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *secondTB;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *symbolLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *find;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

int resultValue=0;

- (IBAction)saveResult:(id)sender {
   //other codes
}

//other methods
@end
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense. you said "connect the IBOutlet to ViewController 's  textbox" . Can you explain a bit more about how to implement it. 
When i click cmd and drag, it doesn't show any option like you said

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to reuse from that text box? If you just simply want to use the text value, just pass it as a parameter from BaseViewController to DerivedViewController. Otherwise, you need to subclass UITextField to use on both view controllers.

Comment: No.. I want to use the Textbox not just contents of textbox.